# Multithreading ping inside BASH script

Tags: multithreading, bash

I've had a look around here and there only seems to be one question raised in regards to the multithreading of ping inside a BASH environment.

**Code**

```
data=$(<~/Desktop/hosts.txt)
    for line in $data
    do
      ping -c1 $line &> /dev/null &
        echo $line is reachable ||
        echo $line is down
     done
```

The issue is that it cycles through the IP address range inside the file and reports all of the IP addresses as reachable when in fact only 3 out of /24 are reachable...

I've attempted to slow the scan down by adding `-W 1` to the ping but this results in substandard performance and necessitates the use of multithreading

Comment: The `&` runs the `ping` process in the background so your status reporting below is only reporting that it `ping` was found and executed (not what happened when `ping` exited) . Using shell scripting, I don't think there is a way to speed this up. Look for a better tool that is designed to do scans of IP ranges. `nmap` comes to mind. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Shelter I guess this explains why it is so hard to find what I'm looking for, I'm aware of nmap but was hoping to find the same effect in Bash as nmap is not installed by default

Comment: bash doesn't support multithreading at all. `foo &` runs a new *process*, not a thread.

Answer (score 4):

As coded you've got 2 separate, unrelated commands:

```
# run `ping` and place in background
ping -c1 $line &
```

and

```
# regardless of what the `ping` command does ... always
# print 'reachable` and if that fails print `down`
echo $line is reachable || echo $line is down
```

I'm assuming what you really want is to use the results of the `ping` (success or failure) to determine which `echo` command to issue; in this case you need to replace the single `&` with a double `&&' like such:

```
ping -c1 $line &&
echo $line is reachable ||
echo $line is down
```

While this should provide the conditional output, your pings are now performed one-at-a-time in the foreground.

If you want to run your pings in the background (ie, 'multithreaded') **and** also perform the conditional printing, you could place the `ping/echo/echo` code inside a function, then in your `for` loop make a call to the function ... making sure to place the function call in the background, eg:

Sample list of sites to ping:

```
$ cat pinglist
www.yahoo.com
www.google.com
www.peanut_butter.and_jelly
www.bbc.co.uk
www.not_today_your.not
```

Proposed script:

```
$ cat pinger
#!/bin/bash
function pingit () {

    target=${1}

    # send stdout/stderr to /dev/null since all we need is the return code

    ping -c1 ${target} >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
    echo ${target} is reachable ||
    echo ${target} is down
}

data=$(<pinglist)

for line in ${data}
do
    # call our function and place the call in the background

    pingit ${line} &
done

# wait for all outstanding background jobs to complete before continuing

wait

# [optional] let operator know we're done.
echo "Completed."
```

Some sample runs, keeping in mind that the order of the output messages will vary based on how quickly each `ping` command completes:

```
$ pinger
www.yahoo.com is reachable
www.google.com is reachable
www.peanut_butter.and_jelly is down
www.bbc.co.uk is reachable
www.not_today_your.not is down
Completed.

$ pinger
www.peanut_butter.and_jelly is down
www.not_today_your.not is down
www.google.com is reachable
www.bbc.co.uk is reachable
www.yahoo.com is reachable
Completed.
```

We'll run the test again and sort the output, ignoring the 'Completed.' message:

```
$ pinger | egrep -v "Completed" | sort
www.bbc.co.uk is reachable
www.google.com is reachable
www.not_today_your.not is down
www.peanut_butter.and_jelly is down
www.yahoo.com is reachable
```

---

!!! Keep in mind that if you've got a long list of hosts to ping and you're running this script on a smallish box, your sysadmin might not be too happy if you kick off 10's of thousands of simultaneous `ping` calls ... and heaven forbid you make a coding mistake that spawns an infinite loop of `ping` commands.

This type of misbehavior can be coded for (eg, limiting the number of outstanding `ping` calls, or `sleep`ing for a couple seconds after every X number of `ping` calls, etc), but I'll leave that coding as homework ;-)

---

If you don't want to bother with a function (eg, you're doing a quick command line loop/ping), you could wrap the `ping/echo/echo` in parentheses and run this construct in the background, though you'll want to decide how to handle the job-related messages, eg:

```
$ data=$(<pinglist)
$ for line in ${data}
do
    (ping -c1 ${line} >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo ${line} is reachable || echo ${line} is down) &
done
[1]     12212
[2]     12213
[3]     12214
[4]     12215
[5]     12217
www.google.com is reachable
www.peanut_butter.and_jelly is down
www.not_today_your.not is down
www.bbc.co.uk is reachable
www.yahoo.com is reachable
[5] +  Done                    for line in ${data};do;    (ping -c1 ${line} >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo ${line} is reachable || echo ${line} is down) & 2>/dev/null;done
[4] -  Done                    for line in ${data};do;    (ping -c1 ${line} >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo ${line} is reachable || echo ${line} is down) & 2>/dev/null;done
[3]    Done                    for line in ${data};do;    (ping -c1 ${line} >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo ${line} is reachable || echo ${line} is down) & 2>/dev/null;done
[2]    Done                    for line in ${data};do;    (ping -c1 ${line} >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo ${line} is reachable || echo ${line} is down) & 2>/dev/null;done
[1]    Done                    for line in ${data};do;    (ping -c1 ${line} >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo ${line} is reachable || echo ${line} is down) & 2>/dev/null;done
```

One option (kludge?) for masking the job related messages requires wrapping our `ping/echo/echo/&` in a set of braces and directing stderr to /dev/null ...

```
$ data=$(<pinglist)
$ for line in ${data}
do
    {(ping -c1 ${line} >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo ${line} is reachable || echo ${line} is down) & } 2>/dev/null
done
www.peanut_butter.and_jelly is down
www.not_today_your.not is down
www.google.com is reachable
www.yahoo.com is reachable
www.bbc.co.uk is reachable
```

... though this could mask some error messages that you may be interested in, ymmv.

Comment: Incredible answer, however I'll only ever be sending ICMP to /24 subnet range, I'm testing thoroughly on virtual machines at the minute

Answer (score 1):

I would let **GNU Parallel** do them all in parallel for me, probably 32 at a time:

```
parallel -j 32 -a hosts.txt 'ping -c1 {} > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo {} is available || echo {} is down'
```