# ping test multi threading using bash

Tags: multithreading, bash

I'm trying to check the health of more than 2500 servers using ping -c1 test. For checking single server it takes 1.5 secs. For this excecution takes almost 1.5 hrs. I want to cut shot this excecution nearly 10 mins or 15 mins, so thought of enable threads in bash scripting. And I noticed " parallel " provided by epel which enhances the multithreading feature.

May I know is there any alternative to achieve this? I would prefer bash than any other language.

Thanks

Comment: how about making multiple server lists and run multiple ping script on those lists parallely in background.

Comment: bash is not the best solution for your requirement. there are tools like if you really want to stick to bash `parallel` or `fping`

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46027261/2836621

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool called [`fping`](https://fping.org/) which can read from an input file:

```
fping hosts.txt
```

The program doesn't need to be multi threaded because a single process / thread can ping multiple hosts at the same time.

---

Alternatively you may use good old `nmap` which is also able to perform ping testing - in parallel:

```
nmap -n -sP -iL hosts.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not get the full speedup you are looking for, but have you tried running each process in the background?  Something like so:

```
for i in {1..100} ; 
    do     ( /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 & ); 
done
```